# R, stringr - replace multiple characters from rows in a datframe

Tags: r, dataframe, str-replace, stringr

I have addresses stored in "address" column in a store dataframe, I would like to create a new column with the following corrections on existing addresses:

```
{"ST": "STREET",
  "RD": "ROAD",
  "AVE": "AVENUE",
  "N": "NORTH",
  "W": "WEST",
  "S": "SOUTH",
  "E": "EAST",
  "STE": "SUITE",
  "HWY": "HIGHWAY",
  "DR": "DRIVE",
  "NW": "NORTH WEST",
  "NE": "NORTH EAST",
  "SW": "SOUTH WEST",
  "SE": "SOUTH EAST",
  "LN": "LANE",
  "WAY": "WAY"}
```

How should I move forward this?

Expected output:

101 ST LN -> 101 STREET LANE

Comment: can you show the expceted ouput

Comment: @akrun For example if we have "101 ST LN" as an existing address, I want the new address to be "101 STREET LANE"

Comment: Try converting your data into a named vector. Then use `stringr::str_replace_all`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to this problem is to use `stri_replace_all_regex` from `stringi`. It accepts vectorized patterns and replacements.

We can use the `\b` wildcard for word boundaries, which itself needs to be escaped to `\\b`. To take care of the case when the abbreviation ends with a `.`, we can match a literal `.` or `\b` with `(\\.|\\b)`.

I make the pattern and replacement vectors from your data at the end of the answer.

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_regex("101 ST. LN",pattern = terms[[1]], replacement = terms[[2]],vectorize_all = FALSE)
[1] "101 STREET LANE"
```

The same works for a vector of strings to have replacements made.

```
data <- data.frame(address = c("1 N ST", "2 E AVE", "3 S RD", "4 SE LN"))
stri_replace_all_regex(data$address,pattern = terms[[1]], replacement = terms[[2]],vectorize_all = FALSE)
#[1] "1 NORTH STREET"    "2 EAST AVENUE"     "3 SOUTH ROAD"      "4 SOUTH EAST LANE"
```

**Data**

```
terms <- c("ST", "STREET", "RD", "ROAD", "AVE", "AVENUE", "N", "NORTH", 
"W", "WEST", "S", "SOUTH", "E", "EAST", "STE", "SUITE", "HWY", 
"HIGHWAY", "DR", "DRIVE", "NW", "NORTH WEST", "NE", "NORTH EAST", 
"SW", "SOUTH WEST", "SE", "SOUTH EAST", "LN", "LANE", "WAY", 
"WAY")
terms <- split(terms,rep(1:2,times = length(terms) / 2))
terms[[1]] <- paste0("\\b",terms[[1]],"(\\.|\\b)")
terms[[1]]
# [1] "\\bST(\\.|\\b)"  "\\bRD(\\.|\\b)"  "\\bAVE(\\.|\\b)" "\\bN(\\.|\\b)"   "\\bW(\\.|\\b)"   "\\bS(\\.|\\b)"   "\\bE(\\.|\\b)"  
# [8] "\\bSTE(\\.|\\b)" "\\bHWY(\\.|\\b)" "\\bDR(\\.|\\b)"  "\\bNW(\\.|\\b)"  "\\bNE(\\.|\\b)"  "\\bSW(\\.|\\b)"  "\\bSE(\\.|\\b)" 
#[15] "\\bLN(\\.|\\b)"  "\\bWAY(\\.|\\b)"
terms[[2]]
# [1] "STREET"     "ROAD"       "AVENUE"     "NORTH"      "WEST"       "SOUTH"      "EAST"       "SUITE"      "HIGHWAY"    "DRIVE"     
#[11] "NORTH WEST" "NORTH EAST" "SOUTH WEST" "SOUTH EAST" "LANE"       "WAY"
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I apologize but what would you do if you have cases where the string like "ST" can end with a "."

For example, I have entries in my store data frame where the address is 

101 N ST. -> this transforms to -> 101 North ST.

Comment: You can use `(\\.|\\b)` to match a period or word boundary. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, with `str_replace_all`from package `stringr`:

```
df <- data.frame(address = c("12 ST W", "333 AVE", "45 RD", "666 STE E"))

str_replace_all(df$address,c("\\bST\\b" = "STREET",
                             "\\bRD\\b" = "ROAD",
                             "\\bAVE\\b" = "AVENUE",
                             "\\bN\\b" = "NORTH",
                             "\\bW\\b" = "WEST",
                             "\\bE\\b" = "EAST",
                             "\\bSTE\\b" = "SUITE"))
[1] "12 STREET WEST" "333 AVENUE"     "45 ROAD"        "666 SUITE EAST"
```